# What does the following assembly code really do?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, low-level

I am not sure what the following is supposed to do but this is what I got so far.

[image]

```
mov eax, 5       (move 5 into register eax)   
add eax, ebx     (add 5 from eax to 0 from ebx and store in eax)
nop              (no operation)
nop              (no operation)
push ebx         (push 0 onto the hardware stack)
nop              (no operation)
pop ebx          (pop the 0 from off the stack and store in ebx)
call [eax]       (get the 5 from eax)
```

Comment: What the instructions do depends upon the syntax (Intel or AT&T). Since you appear to be using Intel assembly syntax, it is true that `mov eax, 5` moves a `5` into register `eax`. But, `add eax, ebx` adds `ebx` to `eax`, not vice versa. So after this instruction, the contents of `eax` is then 5 plus whatever `ebx` was and `ebx` is unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corrected description for fragment A is:

```
mov eax, 5       ; move 5 into register eax
add eax, ebx     ; add contents of ebx to eax, changing eax
nop              ; no operation
nop              ; no operation
push ebx         ; push contents of ebx onto the stack
nop              ; no operation
pop ebx          ; pop top of the stack into ebx
call [eax]       ; call the subroutine pointed to at location [eax]
```

The `nop` instructions followed by `push ebx` followed by `nop` followed by `pop ebx` again don't change anything (other than leaving the former value of `ebx` at an available location in stack space). So functionally (although with reduced number of consumed CPU cycles and code space), this is equivalent to:

```
mov eax, 5       ; move 5 into register eax
add eax, ebx     ; add contents of ebx to eax, changing eax
call [eax]       ; call the subroutine pointed to at location [eax]
```

Fragment B is:

```
mov eax, 5       ; move 5 into register eax
push ecx         ; push contents of ecx onto the stack
pop ecx          ; pop top of the stack into ecx
add eax, ebx     ; add contents of ebx to eax, changing eax
swap eax, ebx    ; swap the contents of eax and ebx
swap ebx, eax    ; swap the contents of eax and ebx
call [eax]       ; call the subroutine pointed to at location [eax]
nop              ; no operation
```

Swapping two registers twice in a row has no net effect, other than consuming CPU cycles and code space. So fragment B functionally boils down to:

```
mov eax, 5       ; move 5 into register eax
add eax, ebx     ; add contents of ebx to eax, changing eax
call [eax]       ; call the subroutine pointed to at location [eax]
```

Functionally the same as fragment A.

Comment: Your description of the `call` instruction isn't quite right.  It's a memory-indirect call, so `EAX` is only the address of the function pointer, not the value (the location of the subroutine itself). `EIP = [EAX]`, not `EIP = EAX`.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes good catch. I was one level of indirect off.

Comment: Really helpful, thanks much for this explanation, I am definitely on my way to understanding fully, one thing still eludes me you said  call [eax]   means  call the subroutine pointed to at location [eax], but what subroutine are you talking about and where did it come from does the [] around the register mean something special?

Comment: @SeanSogMiller, the brackets indicate that what's inside is the address of what is desired. In this case, the value of `eax` depends upon what the value of `ebx` coming into the code. That information is not stated, so we don't know what subroutine. We only know it's address is at the location given in `eax`.

Answer (score 1):

Two code fragments do indirect call through EAX. If EBX value in both fragments is the same, the same code will be called as both fragments add ebx to eax.